# Where is Michael Mamaril?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

In tribute to a *Borderlands* fan by the real name of Michael Mamaril who died from cancer at a young age, Gearbox immortalized him as an NPC vault hunter who offers you guns to help you out ([source](http://www.gamefront.com/borderlands-2-tribute-to-a-vault-hunter-achievement-guide-video/)). The "Tribute to a Vault Hunter" achievement triggers upon finding him.

I haven't been able to find him in Sanctuary in single or multiplayer. I've completed multiple story missions and still cannot find him. Is there some trick to when he begins to show up in Sanctuary? I know he hangs around in many different spots—are they random or predictable?

Comment: The Achievement is there, just cannot find him. It seems to me like it's a bug.

Comment: @desaivv Still haven't found him, the game is great and since I'm not an achievement hunter it doesn't bother me too much. I'll still withhold accepting until someone's advice actually gets me to him.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Michael Mamaril** can be found in the **Sanctuary** (you don't need any quest requirement for him,he starts showing as soon you get in Sanctuary).

There is a chance he will "spawn" in one of his spawn locations (i personally found him twice next to the Hostel door) in Sanctuary everytime you come to the town.

**Michael Mamaril Locations (screenshot and work by me):**

[image]

**Additional info:**

- Michael Mamaril will give you a blue weapon or item when you talk to him
- The items he gives you are scaled to your level
- You can constantly leave and re-enter town via fast-travel to reset his spawning and therefore farm free items from him
- In the unpatched console versions, Michael has a 100% spawn chance before Sanctuary is relocated
- His spawn chance on PC and on patched console version is always 10%

Comment: I was told he only resets after completing a story quest. Is that no longer true?

Comment: @SadlyNot Well Iv'e found him 3 or 4 times now and I'm mostly doing only sidequests (i do story quests only when I'm out of sidequests) so i don't think that's true.

Comment: @SadlyNot on Xbox I've found him almost every time I've returned to Sanctuary.

Comment: Sounds good to me :D

Comment: Indeed he's just a really rare spawn on PC, I managed to find him in one of the locations listed. If any details surface about how to  reliably get him please let me know.

Comment: @toNyldaS I don't think Gearbox will change his "spawn" rate for PC version, but if they do I'll let you know.

Comment: @toNyldaS Added some more info that you might find interesting/useful (under additional info).

Comment: I have been replaying the game since Oct 2013. I have yet to see him. Each time I get to Sanctuary, I go through all the possible locations (all those listed here as well as in front of the fast travel building - I think i found him there once on another play-through). I have yet to find him. I've been looking since before Sanctuary took flight. I've just killed the Warrior and still no sign of MM. I'm playing on PS3.

Comment: I found him tonight in under the stairs Scooter's garage. I was seriously beginning to wonder if he had been removed or made more scarce. Glad to know he's still around.

Answer (score 11):

For the Tribute To A Vault Hunter (15 points / Bronze) achievement when you reach the town of Sanctuary, you can find Mike Mamaril hanging around some of the town’s major landmarks.

Partial list of locations he can be found at:

- Inside the Crimson Raider’s HQ
- Zed’s Clinic
- The News Stand
- Claptrap’s Corner
- Moxxie's place (across from Sir Hammerlock)

and other random locations around the city.

Here is a video example:

### **EDIT**

There are reports that at first I concluded it must be a bug on the PC version of the game. But as reports started coming in from other forums, it seems Mike is a very rare spawn on PC. On consoles people find him very easily.

[Here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=97795479) is one Steam user who found him on PC. Posting the screen shot to avoid link rot.

[image: Mike Mamaril PC Screen Capture]

I followed the discussion at Gearbox forums for the past few days since I posted this answer. And this is what I am concluding. Whether this was intentional or a bug, I can not tell. More likely some int value got a bit higher in porting it across platforms.

[No Michael on PC?](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=2779694)

[Has ANYONE who plays on PC found Michael Mamaril?](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=2773794)

[If you HAVE found Michael Mamaril on PC version, post here](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=2773721)

Comment: I still haven't been able to find him. Is he unlocked at a certain point in the story? Does he only show up during certain times of the day? After completely exploring sanctuary on 3 different occasions I'm convinced he's not there 100% of the time.

Comment: Apparantly (some dude on the gearbox forums said so) the non-pc versions are bugged and have a 100% spawn rate. While the pc version has only a 10% spawn rate.

Comment: @desaiw As far as I can tell it isn't official.

Comment: I found him on PC after about 10 tries or so: http://imgur.com/a/HUIYF The [E] to talk shows that I am playing on PC.

Answer (score 3):

I found him in the gun store. He gave me a badass fire pistol. The store is in the Sanctuary and it's a store not a vending machine. I'm playing on the PS3.

Answer (score 2):

I once found him by the Piano in Moxxie's place. I would check there!

Answer (score 2):

Michael Mamaril's 100% spawn chance before Sanctuary is relocated is a bug ([for the console versions, according to this Gearbox forum post by a Community Manager](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=167351)). This has now been fixed with the recent [2012-10-09 patch](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=167351):

> Corrected spawn rate of Michael Mamaril in Sanctuary.

This patch makes his spawn rates return to the default 10%. In the PC version, he always has the normal 10% spawn chance.

Answer (score 1):

found him 3 times on pc
1. at Marcus
2. at Moxxi
3. at HQ

3 times only in 2 full play-through

Comment: There is nothing you can do to make him appear. but I will suggest this. load sanctuary over and over and visit all the possible places everything. you can miss him even if he is in front  of you. How he looks he wears specs and there is always a gun on his back (like a vault hunter).     Three possible locations are     1.Marcus(Inside his shop in front of Marcus)     2.Moxxi(Near slot machines)       3.HQ(ground floor near the stairs)    best of luck finding him.