# Can you get legendary weapons in Vending Machines?

Tags: borderlands-2

Very similar to some vending machines in Borderlands 1 (There was a "secret" vending machine in New Haven that would have very high legendary spawn rates), can vending machines in Borderlands 2 spawn Legendary weapons?

What affects their spawn rate? Level? Class?

Comment: Do you mean actual vending machines or the slot machines?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the answers [on this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85837/do-legendary-drops-only-come-from-specific-bosses) also answer this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can buy legendary (orange) weapons in normal vending machines. I can not find any written souce, but I've personally purchased a [Shredifier](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Shredifier) from a gun machine at Raiders HQ in Sanctuary.

I'd assume any legendary that is marked as "drops from any suitable loot source" in the wiki can spawn in a vending machine. Level of the item is equal to the level of vending machine, which is equal to area level - if you go to Southern Shelf on Normal, you'll forever see level 4-6-something items there. As for "class", the type of item is rolled first, than it has the chance to become legendary - no specific rules.

Also, as Dave mentions, there are Torgue machines with legendaries for Torgue tokens, and Seraph vendor with seraph equipment for Seraph crystals.

Answer (score 5):

In Mr. Torgue's Campgain of Carnage, there are vending machines where you can buy weapons with Torgue Tokens. The item of the day in these machines are **always** legendary. They are quite expensive considering that Torgue Tokens are hard to acquire, however.