# How do I get legendaries at my level?

Tags: borderlands-2

I play Borderlands 2, and I dont have a legendary weapon. I heard Knuckledragger drops one, but I keep farming him on level 1, and he just drops a cheap Hornet. How do I get him to drop a Hornet of my level?  I'm at level 32.I already unlocked True Vault Hunter mode, but I was wondering if I need to farm on that mode? How do I get him to respawn? How do I get other enemies to respawn? Also, I was wondering about raid bosses. Where do I find them?
Thanks guys

Comment: What do you mean you're farming him on level 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Legendary drops only come from specific bosses?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85837/do-legendary-drops-only-come-from-specific-bosses)

Comment: There's also the Leviathan glitch in the Captain Scarlett DLC. But you need the DLC and some people don't like using glitches and such.

Answer (score 8):

You need to beat him at your level in order to get a higher level drop. On the first playthrough the areas don't scale So he'll always be level 1 and drop level 1 gear.

You need true vault-hunter mode (which will cause all their areas to re-scale starting from 30) or ultimate vault-hunter mode (where areas scale to your current level). To unlock those you have to beat the game, but once you have you can go back and forth between replay modes and you keep all your gear.

You should always farm at the highest level that you've unlocked if what you want is gear.

Raid bosses are for once you've beaten level 50. They drop the best loot, but are really intended to be a tougher challenge for UVHM and levels 50+ They are quests given out once you've cleared all the story quests in an area.

Answer (score -2):

You need to kill specific bosses like Doc Mercy or The Bunker over and over again with the best weapons. You have to get the orange variant of weapons or legendary weapons.